# A bag of marbles has 12 red, 7 yellow, 5 blue and 1 white. Find the probability of selecting 4 marbles from the bag where all 4 are red.

Tags: probability

A bag of marbles has 12 red, 7 yellow, 5 blue and 1 white. Find the probability of selecting 4 marbles from the bag where all 4 are red.

The questions is simple, im just having problems with it.
a. 1/64
b. 1/4
c. 1/75900
d. 9/230

Comment: $\dfrac{\binom{12}{4}}{\binom{12+7+5+1}{4}}=\dfrac{9}{230}$

Comment: The probability the first is red is $\frac{12}{25}$. Given the first was red, the probability the second is red is $\frac{11}{24}$. And so on.

Comment: That looks like a homework problem. You shouldn't post homework problems here.

Comment: Dont know how you got that answer but thanks Barak